# C# - Selenium - firefox driver fails to capture and apply AcceptInsecureCerts (2018/02/08 Latest Releases)

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

Hello (first time posting here),

I am having trouble getting geckodriver to bypass certificate errors. I've done a lot of research and made sure that I have the latest versions of all components. Reason I stress that is because a lot of the past questions that exist on this site discuss obsolete methods such as using DesiredCapabilities.

This is my code:

```
FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile("QA"){
    AcceptUntrustedCertificates = true
};
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions(){
    Profile = profile
};
var driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.ca");
```

The code above fails and I still get certificate errors on Firefox. One thing I noticed when debugging it is that the driver still sees the capability "acceptInsecureCerts" as "false". Screenshot below.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Please advise.

I am currently using:

- Selenium V3.9 (latest)
- Mozilla Firefox Nightly 60.0a (latest)
- geckodriver 19.1 (latest)

Comment: The following site can be used to run a quick test it needed https://untrusted-root.badssl.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aah! Found it: Firefox Options has an "addcapabilities" function that fixes it.

```
options.AddAdditionalCapability("acceptInsecureCerts", true, true);
```